# is it possible to create a google form that posts directily to a google site page?

Tags: google-sites, google-forms

I want to make a comment like form that users can post things for other users to read (kind of like a blog) Is this possible to do with google sites/google form? if so, can you please point me to the right direction? I only seem to find ways to post forms to email or to spreadsheets.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is somewhat possible in a round-about kind of way, but not in a direct way. I've been working on this a little myself.

The workflow is

1. Form posts to spreadsheet
2. Spreadsheet is set to publish results via ATOM or RSS feed
3. Retrieve data from spreadsheet using Google Feeds API / JavaScript
4. Dynamically construct a simple webpage

Comment: Thanks, and by dynamically constructing a webpage i would have to do this using app script?

Comment: Yes. If you look at the page that I link to you can view the source code and see how simple this is. The most complex / time consuming part is the styling of the page.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there's a more simple way suitable, like [DISQUS](http://www.disqus.com) or some other 'out-of-box' posting and commenting solution?

Usually they are much more comprehensive: different social networks authentication, attachments, avatars, replies, notifications and so on.

[Disqus for Google Sites](https://code.google.com/p/google-sites-disqus/) is very easy to use.

Comment: Hey Thank you for this i didnt even know it existed